# How to slice a string in reverse in Python?

Tags: python, string, slice

I understand how to normally slice a string and reverse it, but don't get how to do both simultaneously.

Let's say

```
message="hi there"
```

And I wanna select only the "there" part and reverse it, so the output will be "ereht".

Is there a way to do it? Preferably using only the "message" variable, but any other ways are ok, too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What output are you getting?

Comment: Hint: Slice notation supports a step, similar to "range".

Comment: Slicing in python works like this `[start:end:step]`. For each of those values you can use negative values. So think about what a negative step value would do.

Comment: @Cam I tried including other variables that are just sliced pieces of the "message" variable and then reversing the second one, like this:

`message="hi there"

message2=message[3:]

print(message2[::-1])`

But I just wanted to know how to do it using only the given variable, but people in the answers cleared the fog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would split the string and then reverse it part you desire

```
rev = message.split()[-1][::-1]
```

This solution will also work for the example given in the OP (credit to Kelly Bundy):

```
rev = message[:-6:-1]
```

Comment: This isn't doing "both simultaneously".

Comment: @KellyBundy show us how then

Comment: message[:2:-1] or message[:-6:-1]

Comment: @KellyBundy your first solution doesn't work how you think it does

Comment: Depends on what version you mean. As posted now, it does work (I had a typo initially).

Comment: I think both are viable solutions. Strictly speaking `message[:-6:-1] ` is the one that does both *simultaneously* so answers OP's question exactly, but I still believe the solution with `split()` is the better one as it will work for any two (or more words), the other is quite fragile.

Comment: @KellyBundy its safer to use the answer everyone else is giving because your answer is string length dependent and has to be modified each time

Comment: @Mushroomator Depends on what one wants. OP didn't say they want the last word reversed. What if they want the 'here' part reversed? Then the split fails. The way it's worded, the question asks for the [:...:-1] method.

Comment: Fair point. Probably worth adding those considerations and possible methods to the answer @stefan_aus_hannover to give OP the ability to make a conscious decision.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific question, you can use this:

```
message.split()[-1][::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select the second slice with [1] and then reverse it using [::-1]

`message.split()[1][::-1]`